# Expression trees - substitute expression

Tags: c#, expression-trees

Consider two expression trees:

```
Expression<Func<float, float, float>> f1 = (x, y) => x + y;
Expression<Func<float, float>> f2 = x => x * x;
```

I want to substitute the expression `f2` as a second parameter of `f1` and obtain the following expression:

```
Expression<Func<float, float, float>> f3 = (x, y) => x + y * y;
```

The simplest way is to use `Expression.Lambda` and `Expression.Invoke`, but the result will look like

```
(x, y) => f1(x, f2(y))
```

But this is unacceptable for me due to ORM limitations that cannot handle invoke/lambda properly.

Is it possible to construct the expression without full traversal of expression trees? A working example that fulfill my needs can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/e673/6d5a389c7ee87490e3e59d152b0e5ff9) but I want simpler solution.

Comment: Without full traversal of expression trees - no. Basically you need parameter replacer, which is implemented with `ExpressionVisitor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it without full traversal of both expressions. Fortunately, `ExpressionVisitor` makes full traversal really easy:

```
class ReplaceParameter : ExpressionVisitor {
    private readonly Expression replacement;
    private readonly ParameterExpression parameter;
    public ReplaceParameter(
        ParameterExpression parameter
    ,   Expression replacement
    ) {
        this.replacement = replacement;
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
        return node == parameter ? replacement : node;
    }
}
```

Use this visitor twice to complete the replacement:

```
Expression<Func<float,float,float>> f1 = (x, y) => x + y;
Expression<Func<float,float>> f2 = x => x * x;
var pX = f2.Parameters[0];
var pY = f1.Parameters[1];
var replacerF2 = new ReplaceParameter(pX, pY);
var replacerF1 = new ReplaceParameter(pY, replacerF2.Visit(f2.Body));
var modifiedF1 = Expression.Lambda(
    replacerF1.Visit(f1.Body)
,   f1.Parameters
);
Console.WriteLine(modifiedF1);
```

The above prints

```
(x, y) => (x + (y * y))
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/L3OoXp#stdin)